# Bash Prompt returning error code

Tags: command-line, bashrc, error-handling

I've been struggling with this for a bit and no matter what I do it always returns 0 or a green check...

This is in .bashrc

```bsh
Red='\e[0;31m'
Purple='\e[0;35m'
checkmark='\342\234\223'

function error_state()
{
    if [[ $? == 0  ]]; then
        echo "\[$Green\]\[$checkmark\]";
    else
        echo "\[$Red\]\[$?\]";
fi

PS1="\n \\[$Purple\]\342\224\214\342\224\200 \\[$Purple\][ \\[$(error_state)\] \\[$Purple\]]"
```

Comment: You are missing `Green=''` variable.

Comment: When using double quotes `PS1=""` you need to escape subcommands \$(error_state) else the `$()` will be evaluated when the variable PS1 is set

Comment: found it, you can read more [here](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x279.html)

Comment: I wonder if you would be better off using the `PROMPT_COMMAND` hook rather than trying to evaluate a command substitution inside `PS1` directly?

Comment: ... as described here: [bash prompt and echoing colors inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13997892/4440445)

Answer (score 1):

I would *pass* the current status to the function:

```bsh
$(error_state "$?")
```

and

```bsh
error_state() {
    if [[ "$1" -eq 0 ]]; then  ...
        echo "\[$Green\]\[$checkmark\]";
    else
        echo "\[$Red\]\[$1\]";
    fi
}
```

Comment: Hey Glenn...  thanks for the info.  I have added the parameter and now the if statement always evaluates as false and returns the else condition.  the good news is its returning the error code but the bad news is its always red.  for some reason the [[ "$1" -eq 0 ]] condition wont evaluate as true.